# TideSDK bring window to top level on click of system notification

Tags: windows, desktop-application, tidesdk

I am using tideSDK to create desktop app.

I wanted to show the system notifications on certain events. The below code works well.

```
    //Create a callback function for the notification
var doSomething = function() {
    //Do something!
}

//Creating a notification and displaying it.
var notification = Ti.Notification.createNotification({
    'title' : 'Notification from App',
    'message' : 'Click here for updates!',
    'timeout' : 10,
    'callback' : doSomething,
    'icon' : 'app://images/notificationIcon.png'        
});

notification.show();
```

this from http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Notification

Here in `doSomething` method I want to bring the tideSDK app window to top level.

I tried `Ti.UI.currentWindow.focus();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTopMost` together with `show` can be used to **achieve this**

```
var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
window.setTopMost(true);
window.show()
window.setTopMost(false);
```

It is important to do `setTopMost(false)`, otherwise the window will always show on top of other windows even if you want to open other windows